# Is there an expansion of $(\mathbb{N},+,<)$ by a pairing function that is still NIP?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

I was told once that there is a theory consisting of just a pairing function that is stable, although I cannot find a reference for it. This motivated my question, which is essentially the title, although really a simpler question should be asked first:

> Is there an expansion of $(\mathbb{N},<)$ by a pairing function that is still nice in the sense of neo-stability?

Obviously it can't still be o-minimal or dp-minimal, but in principle it could be NIP. Assuming a positive answer to that question it's natural to ask how much more structure is compatible with 'niceness,' hence the question in the title:

> Is there an expansion of $(\mathbb{N},+,<)$ by a pairing function that is still NIP?

I'm primarily interested in the theory of the expansion being NIP, rather than the weaker notion of the structure itself being NIP, as introduced by [Khanaki and Pillay](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04674), although I would be interested in that if the harder question has a negative answer.

EDIT: I recently learned a relevant result of Cegielski and
Richard from [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397500001134) paper, the structure $(\mathbb{N},<,c)$, where $c$ denotes the standard Cantor pairing function $c(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)(x+y+1)+x$, defines addition and multiplication, so is of course not NIP.

Comment: By a pairing function on $X$, you mean an injective function $X\times X\to X$? Do you require subjectivity?

Comment: I was originally thinking a bijection but if it's possible with a strictly injective function I'd be interested in that too.

Comment: Adding the pairing function $(x,y)=x+2^{x+y}$ retains decidability, so that is promising.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Francoise Point, On the Expansion $(N,+,2^x)$ of Presburger Arithmetic, http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~point/papiers/Pres.pdf.  The function in her title is interdefinable with the pairing function I suggested.

Comment: By contrast, any polynomial pairing function will yield a definition of multiplication, and thus will be IP.  So a surjective pairing function would have to be messy to meet your requirements.  (To get from polynomials to multiplication, see Point’s citation of Buchi, or note that we can use a higher-degree polynomial to define a lower-degree polynomial via $p(x+1)-p(x)$, and then get $(x+y)^2-x^2-y^2=2xy$.)